# Is there any reason not to write directly to a hardware overlay files

Tags: io, usb, embedded-linux

So often when working with io pins (gpio, pwm, usb), there will be a file in the file structure that related directly to the io pin, and people will often modify the pin using `echo val > file` and `cat file`. Is there any reason to not just write to this file using fopen or file.read/write?

Specifically now I'm working with a usb device which uses SPCI, and I've been having a variety of permissions issues that have made it hard to use pyusb or pyvisa, but I can `echo` to the device in `/dev/device_file` just fine. I've done similar stuff with gpio pins with no ill effects.

I really appreciate any input you have (as well as links talking about the issue). I've been trying to find more info on this but for some reason I can't seem to find anything talking about it (presumably I'm just using the wrong terms, but still I've made little progress on the issue).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that when you mention "file.read/write", you are referring to the functions in the Python standard library for reading from and writing to files.  No, there should be no issue with using those functions to write to GPIO and PWM files, and that would be preferable because then you avoid creating a new shell process to parse your command, and potentially creating new processes for the `echo` and `cat` commands.

If you are curious, you can use the `strace` utility on your Python program and also on the equivalent shell commands to compare what they are doing, but you shouldn't really need to for these simple cases.